# Modal in React not working. Showing errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hello I was creating a simple CRUD application and everything was working fine. Initially, when you wanted to delete something from this list, you hit the Delete button and it would delete that item. Then I decided to implement a modal function to the delete button, which meant moving and adding some code around. Thats when I am having alot of trouble. I have installed react-bootstrap using npm. I have given my code below. I created a new component ModalItem and removed the handlsubmit function from the TableRow component and put it in the modal component instead. In the TableRow component, where there was originally the handlesubmit function, I put a if/else show function and a toggleModal function and modified the delete button to have modal modal functionality instead of taking to the backend server(that is now handled by the delete button in the modal. The code is not working now. Plus VS code is saying i have errors in the export default ModalItem statement for some reason. Please help.

```
ModalItem.js
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ItemService from './ItemService';

class ModalItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.addItemService = new ItemService();
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    render() {
    // Render nothing if the "show" prop is false
        if(!this.props.show) {
            return null;
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {  //this is showing error at the curly bracket. unexpected token. not sure whats wrong here
        event.preventDefault();
        this.addItemService.deleteData(this.props.obj._id);
    }

    return(
    <div className="static-modal">
        <Modal.Dialog>
            <Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Title>Ready to Delete Student</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>

                <Modal.Body>Are you sure you want to delete this Student?</Modal.Body>

                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={this.props.onClose}>Close</Button>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete" className="btn btn-danger"/>
                    </form>

                </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal.Dialog>
    </div>
    ); 
}

export default ModalItem; //showing error
```

TableRow.js

```
class TableRow extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.addItemService = new ItemService();
      this.state = {isOpen: false}; 
  }

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <tr>
          <td>
            {this.props.obj._id}
          </td>
          <td>
            {this.props.obj.item}
          </td>
          <td>
          <Link to={"/edit/"+this.props.obj._id} className="btn btn-primary">Edit</Link>
        </td>
          <td>
          <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>
            Delete
          </button>
          <div>
            <Modal show={this.state.isOpen}
            onClose={this.toggleModal}>
            </Modal>
          </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
    );
  }
}

export default TableRow;

index.js

import App from './App';
import AddItem from './components/AddItem';
import IndexItem from './components/IndexItem';
import EditItem from './components/EditItem';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
        <Route path='/add-item' component={AddItem} />
        <Route path='/index' component={IndexItem} />
        <Route path='/edit/:id' component={EditItem} />
      </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Backend node code ItemRoutes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var itemRouter = express.Router();

// Require Item model in our routes module
var Item = require('../models/Item');

// Defined store route
itemRouter.route('/add/post').post(function (req, res) {
 var item = new Item(req.body);
      item.save()
    .then(item => {
    res.status(200).json({Item: 'Item added successfully'});
    })
    .catch(err => {
    res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
});

// Defined get data(index or listing) route
itemRouter.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
  Item.find(function (err, itms){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(itms);
    }
  });
});

// Defined edit route
itemRouter.route('/edit/:id').get(function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  Item.findById(id, function (err, item){
      res.json(item);
  });
});

//  Defined update route
itemRouter.route('/update/:id').post(function (req, res) {
  Item.findById(req.params.id, function(err, item) {
    if (!item)
      return next(new Error('Could not load Document'));
    else {
      // do your updates here
      item.item = req.body.item;

      item.save().then(item => {
          res.json('Update complete');
      })
      .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("unable to update the database");
      });
    }
  });
});

// Defined delete | remove | destroy route
itemRouter.route('/delete/:id').get(function (req, res) {
  Item.findByIdAndRemove({_id: req.params.id},
       function(err, item){
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else res.json('Successfully removed');
    });
});

module.exports = itemRouter;
```

Please help me fix my errors in the modalItem.js and TableRow.js because thats where I made all the modifications to include this modal element (which is now causing problems)

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Comment: Not sure yet. Im now running into mongodb connection issues. So cant see whats going on. However, the errors did go away on the frontend side

Comment: Well if the answer helped you out, would be helpful if you set it as accepted

Comment: I am now getting errors on the MoalItem.js file. Developer console says: Warning:React.createElement: type is invalid--expected a string (for built in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file its defined in. Check your code at ModalItem.js:27, ModalItem.js 26. So when i hit the delete button in the page, no modal pops up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that you want to be rendered needs to be inside the `render`.

```
ModalItem.js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ItemService from './ItemService';

class ModalItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addItemService = new ItemService();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {  //this is showing error at the curly bracket. unexpected token. not sure whats wrong here
    event.preventDefault();
    this.addItemService.deleteData(this.props.obj._id);
  }
  render() {
    // Render nothing if the "show" prop is false
    if (!this.props.show) {
      return null;
    }
    else {
      return (
        <div className="static-modal">
          <Modal.Dialog>
            <Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Title>Ready to Delete Student</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>

            <Modal.Body>Are you sure you want to delete this Student?</Modal.Body>

            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button onClick={this.props.onClose}>Close</Button>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" className="btn btn-danger" />
              </form>

            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal.Dialog>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
}

export default ModalItem; //showing error
```

Comment: Hoping somebody bless us with the functional only version of the above.